# AngularJs ng-style not working with Angular-UI 0.6.0 carousel

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-ui

I have an Angular 1.0.7 webapp that is using Angular-UI 0.6.0 to display a carousel.

We are redesigning our website to improve user experience. So, designer suggest to update the way images are displayed. Instead of using img tag, ng-style attribute with background-url with the image is suggested.

This code is working for us (because it´s using just style attribute):

```
<carousel interval="8000">
            <slide style="background-image:url('img/carrusel1.jpg');">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="carousel-caption" ng-cloak>
                        <h1 class="custom-page-header-2">{{'CARROUSEL_TITLE_1' | translate}}</h1>
                        <h2 class="lead">{{'CARROUSEL_CONTENT_1' | translate}}</h2>             
                    </div>
                  </div>
            </slide>
```

However, this one with ng-style (because we need Angular code inside) is not working for us:

```
<carousel interval="-10">
                            <slide ng-repeat="i in inspiration.picturesList" ng-style="{'background-image': 'url(//' + {{S3_BUCKET}} + '.' + {{PHOTO_SERVER_URL}} + '/img/inspiration/ibiza/inspiration-ibiza-1.jpg)'}">
                        </slide>
</carousel>
```

**Update**
According to the comments, I do some updates.

1. As I told, if I just use ng-style whether if I use the format proposed above or the one proposed in the comments, I got this error:

   ```
   Error: Syntax Error: Token ':' is an unexpected token at column 19 of the expression ['background-image': 'url(//{{S3_BUCKET}}.{{PHOTO_SERVER_URL}} + {{inspiration.name}}/inspiration-{{inspiration.name}}-{{i}}.jpg)'] starting at [: 'url(//{{S3_BUCKET}}.{{PHOTO_SERVER_URL}} + {{inspiration.name}}/inspiration-{{inspiration.name}}-{{i}}.jpg)'].
   ```
2. With `ng-attr-style` the error is gone. However, I don´t get the expected result when I inspect the code:

   ```
     ng-attr-style="'background-image': 'url(//. + /inspiration--.jpg)'"
   ```

Looks like it´s not running the Angular code.

This is the code:

```
 <carousel interval="-10">
                                <slide ng-repeat="i in inspiration.picturesList" ng-attr-style="'background-image': 'url(//{{S3_BUCKET}}.{{PHOTO_SERVER_URL}} + {{inspiration.name}}/inspiration-{{inspiration.name}}-{{i}}.jpg)'">
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem just now (with `uib-bar` and `ng-style` not working together). The problem is that the angular-ui directives use `ng-style` internally in their templates, and apparently angular doesn't cope well with multiple `ng-style` directives: it just appends the contents, which can't work.

You nearly got the solution. The key is to use `ng-attr-style`, but it expects its input as text (optionally with `{{..}}` expressions), no need for further quoting. Here is what worked for me:

```
ng-attr-style="background-color: {{colors[$index % colors.length]}}"
```

This should probably solve your problem:

```
<slide ng-repeat="i in inspiration.picturesList"
       ng-attr-style="background-image: url(//{{S3_BUCKET}}{{PHOTO_SERVER_URL}}{{inspiration.name}}/inspiration-{{inspiration.name}}-{{i}}.jpg)">
```

Make sure your `{{S3_BUCKET}}`, `{{inspiration.name}}`, ... variables are properly defined in the local scope (within the `ng-repeat`).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `ng-attr-style`.
Have a look: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2186#issuecomment-68032290

Answer (score 0):

```
ng-style="{'background-image': 'url(//' + {{S3_BUCKET}} + '.' + {{PHOTO_SERVER_URL}} + '/img/inspiration/ibiza/inspiration-ibiza-1.jpg)'}"
```

=>

```
ng-style="{'background-image': 'url(//{{PHOTO_SERVER_URL}}.{{PHOTO_SERVER_URL}}/img/inspiration/ibiza/inspiration-ibiza-1.jpg)'}"
```

{{}} no need quotation split with '+'

And I think if possible, html is simple specially angularjs. (because of many attributes)

so in js code

```
 #coffeescript
 $scope.bg_style = {'background-image':'url('+IMAGE_URL+')}

 #if array with image url
 for i in $scope.images
   i.bg_style = {'background-image':'url('+i.url+')}
```

Comment: @Rober Can you show me your html code for my comment? I think you miss some points. For example, not '[' but '{' and I want know why '+' is in ng-style. Do the image file name have '+' ? (e.g. "my+photo.jpg")